# C++ arrays and strstrok

Tags: c++, arrays, strtok, typed-arrays

I'm working with the arrays in C++. So my input in the array is O3B4F2 and I want to have in output OOOBBBBFF?.. I'm reading about function strtrok but I don't understand that really good because it's dividing sentence on the tokens.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  char a[100+1];
  cin>>a;
  char * pch;
  char dioba[]="0 1 2 3 4 5  6 7 8 9 ";
  pch = strtok (a,dioba);
  int c;
  for(int i=0;i<strlen(a);i++)
  {
      if(isdigit(a[i])==1)
      {

      }
  }
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    cout<<pch<<endl;
    pch = strtok (NULL,dioba);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Also, I try to resolve a similar task where I need to divide the array into sets of the letter. I have output need **togo** and I want to my output look like **ne e d to go**. So after letter e an o, I want to use white space or new line.

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main ()
    {
      char a[100+1];
      cin>>a;
      char b[100+1];
      int  i=0,j=0;
      for(i;i<strlen(a);i++)
       {
        if(a[i]=='a'||a[i]=='e'|| a[i]=='i')
            for(j;j<strlen(a);j++)
            {
                b[j]=' ';
            }
          b[j]= a[i];
         cout<<b<<endl;
       }
      return 0;
     }
```

Comment: You can use walk the input char[] by index or by pointer, no need to use strtok. As for mapping digit chars to numbers, a common trick is to use `c - '0'` to get the digit value.

Comment: Re: `if(isdigit(a[i])==1)` -- this won't work. Read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) for `std::is digit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first case, as mentionned in comments, no need to use strtok. Here is an example of code (although there are many ways to perform the requested task):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main ()
{
  std::string s;
  std::cin >> s;
  std::istringstream stream(s);

  char pch;

  // fetch stream for the character to repeat until the end of the string
  while( stream >> pch )
  {
      char nbChars;
      // fetch length for repetition
      stream >> nbChars;
      // convert character to its integer value
      nbChars -= '0';
      // repeat character as many times as needed
      for(int i=0; i < nbChars;i++)
      {
          std::cout << pch;
      }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

For your second task, I propose this sample code, you can modify letters as needed.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
  std::string s;
  std::string needSpaceChars{"aeo"};

  // read content on standard input
  std::getline(std::cin, s);
  // for each char, check its value and add space after the letters defined in needSpaceChars variable
  for(char pch: s)
  {
      // display character first
      std::cout << pch;
      // add space if character is in the list of characters to handle
      if( needSpaceChars.find(pch) != std::string::npos )
      {
          std::cout << ' ';
      }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you have described the problem, the input will always in form of `char` followed by `int`. Hence you have to pick in pair (`char`, `int`)and print it as per rule.

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < arr.size() - 1;) {
    int val = (int)arr[i+1] - 48;
    for(auto j = 0; i < val; j++) {
        cout << arr[i];
    }
    i += 2;
}
```

1. First `for()` is for traversing through whole `arr`.
2. Second `for()` is for printing the particular `char` for it's number of occurrences.

Note : Since the given `arr` is of type `char` you have to convert the second element of pair from `char` to `int`.